Spanning trees and (induced) fundamental cycles
I had an idea about certain spanning trees of graphs and was wondering if any of you knows something about this.
Given a connected graph $G$, does there always exist a spanning tree such that the its fundamental cycles are actually induced cycles in $G$? Now this certainly does not work for all spanning trees. Take the following figure 8 with spanning tree marked in fat. The fundamental cycle corresponding to the lower edge is not an induced cycle in $G$.

However, we can fix that by choosing the following spanning tree:

I played around with it a bit and it certainly works for cliques $K_n$ by choosing a star as its spanning tree. There should also be a simple construction for $K_{n,n}$'s by starting with a matching and choosing one vertex which we also connect to every other vertex. Then every fundamental cycle is a 4 cycle and must therefore already be an induced cycle in $G$.
I could also not come up with an easy counter example and was therefore wondering if this might be true. Does anyone have any insight on this?
Thank you and best regards!

It is not true. Take the following graph

and focus on the triangle in the middle and note that every cycle that is not a $K_3$ is not induced. We can see that any spanning tree that uses no edge from it gives us a $C_6$ as a fundamental cycle. Similarly any spanning tree that uses one of its edges gives us a $C_5$ and any spanning tree that uses two edges a $C_4$. Lastly we cannot use all three edges. This argument should hold for any graph that is a cycle with cycles attached to each of its edges.
